# Why a question which is a canonical example of "off-topic" is getting answers? What actions can be taken?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Today a new user asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569216/the-number-of-elements-of-pa-for-a-finite-set-a) (Below is the revision 1)

> **can you do it?#challenge**
>
> IF a set A has K elements,formulate a conjecture about the number of elements in p(A). I can't even understand the term conjecture.

The Problems with question:

1. The title is not informative.
2. The OP stated that *I can't even understand the term conjecture*. First, I think OP should at least understand what his/her question is asking.Second,when OP is saying he *I can't **even** understand ...*,What he/she is understanding from question? Does he/she knows what "Set","elements" or "p(A)" means?
3. The question itself is about formulating a conjecture not proving it. And it can be formulated easily by writing down subsets of two or three arbitrary sets.

So why a question like this has gotten 3 answers by high-rep (>2000) users?

**EDIT:**

I know that this is a normal behavior of some users to answer questions that are lacking effort from OP, being unclear poorly formatted and etc. But I think this question is different case because this is not about understanding a simple concept or applying a simple theorem or using a definition. Here some users **Wrote down some examples, guessed(conjecture) and even provided proof with explanation**. I don't expect a question with this quality to be answered  even in a math tutoring website.

My main concern is that if this trend continues. I think this encourages off-topic questions more than the time that homework tag existed. What can be done in order to stop it (beside down voting answers or leaving comment)?

Comment: [This question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/can-i-try-to-tell-experienced-users-not-to-answer-bad-questions) and maybe also the posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/21290) seem to be related to your question. (At least to some extent.)

Comment: Is "I don't except..." a typo? (Perhaps you meant to say *expect* or *accept*?) I am not a native English speaker but I have [learned from here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/except) that except can be used as a verb. And it seems it would mean "I do not object to." (Sorry for turning this comment into ELL stuff. But I am just trying to help to clarify your question. One of the three close votes which have been cast so far is "unclear what you're asking".)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks for pointing out that. I meant expect. Last night I read this [question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/can-i-try-to-tell-experienced-users-not-to-answer-bad-questions) with all comments on it and I think i should close this as duplicate.